# Carto v4 + StoryMap - How to link Carto layer marker data to StoryMap scenes

Tags: javascript, leaflet, cartodb

I have been developing a StoryMap visualisation that works with Carto.js v4 (as per: https://github.com/jakobzhao/storymap/ and esp. this example: https://bl.ocks.org/oriolbx/c2bd7fd47ffd448909daec58f88c28ae). I have been able to setup marker popups plus a bunch of other cool stuff like lines between them and swooping arrows. Unfortunately, when trying to put these markers in different scenes, I have been unable to add the code successfully.

In the code below, I have setup a Carto layer like "const cartLayer = new carto..." and added it to the layer definition (layer: client.getLeafletLayer) and then added a reference to it in the StoryMap section (layers.cartoLayer.layer.addTo(map2).

This works for the layer called cartoLayer in whatever scene I place it in. However, when I want to take out the cartoLayer and just have specific markers in the "Lisgoold" scene using "LisgooldLayer" Carto layer, then the StoryMap section won't recognise the layer definition. I've checked the Carto.js docs and can't find a way to define the layer so that it can be referenced for StoryMap. I am able to get "layer4" to show up no problem, but not lisgooldLayer, and most other layer definitions in other example projects use GEOJson.

Is there something in this code that I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

```
     // set CARTO client
       const client = new carto.Client({
         apiKey: '{CARTO-KEY}',
         username: '{CARTO-USER}'
       });
       const source = new carto.source.SQL('
           SELECT * FROM CARTOSOURCE
       ');
       const sourceLisgoold = new carto.source.SQL('
           SELECT * FROM CARTOSOURCE
           WHERE scene='Lisgoold'
       ');
       // define CartoCSS code to style data on map
       const style = new carto.style.CartoCSS('
         #layer{
             marker-fill: #336699;
             marker-allow-overlap: false;
         }
         #layer
           #layer[scene = "overview"]{
               marker-fill: #fbb4ae;
               marker-allow-overlap: false;
           }
           #layer[scene = "Lisgoold"]{
             marker-width: 20;
               marker-fill: #fbb4ae;
               marker-allow-overlap: false;
           }
           #layer[scene = "Salesman"]{
               marker-fill: #b3cde3;
               marker-allow-overlap: false;
           }
           #layer[scene = "England"]{
               marker-fill: #ccebc5;
               marker-allow-overlap: false;
           }
           #layer[scene = "SalesmanReturn"]{
               marker-fill: #333333;
               marker-allow-overlap: false;
           }
           #layer[scene = "USJourney"]{
               marker-fill: #ffffff;
               marker-allow-overlap: false;
           }
           #layer[scene = "WorkCanada"]{
               marker-fill: #336699;
               marker-allow-overlap: false;
           }
           #layer[scene = "LifeInChicago"]{
               marker-fill: #ff0000;
               marker-allow-overlap: false;
           }
           #layer[scene = "WorkUS"]{
               marker-fill: #fbfbfb;
               marker-allow-overlap: false;
           }
           #layer[scene = "TravelToUs"]{
               marker-fill: #fafafa;
               marker-allow-overlap: false;
           }
           #layer[scene = "FamilyTragedy"]{
               marker-fill: #ccc333;
               marker-allow-overlap: false;
           }

       ');
// create CARTO layer from source and style variables
const cartoLayer = new carto.layer.Layer(source, style, {
 featureOverColumns: (['scene', 'location_address','landmark_not_on_gis'])
});
const lisgooldLayer = new carto.layer.Layer(sourceLisgoold, style, {
 featureOverColumns: (['scene', 'location_address','landmark_not_on_gis'])
});
// add CARTO layer to the client
client.addLayers([cartoLayer, lisgooldLayer]);
// define layers that will be used on the map
var layers = {
           basemap: {
               layer: L.tileLayer('https://cartocdn_{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/base-antique/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')
           },
           cartoLayer: {
               layer: client.getLeafletLayer()
           },
           lisgooldLayer: {
              layer:  lisgooldLayer
           },
           layer4: {  //https://github.com/wbkd/leaflet-swoopy
            layer: L.swoopyArrow([53.4120954,-3.056141], [56.9900112,-31.7339369], {
              text: 'All aboard for Quebec!',
              weight: 10,
              opacity: 0.2,
              fontSize: 20,
              factor: -0.9,
              color: "#bb0017",
              iconAnchor: [0, 0],
              iconSize: [200,150],
              textClassName: "arrow-label"
          })
          },
           layer5: {  //https://github.com/wbkd/leaflet-swoopy
           layer: L.swoopyArrow([54.5945837, -32.0337078], [54.5945837, -39.0337078], {
              text: 'worlds',
              weight: 2,
              opacity: 0.7,
              fontSize: 20,
              color: "#ffea00",
              iconAnchor: [0, 0]
          })
          },
};
// define scenes
let scenes = {
           overview: { lat: 51.9735556, lng: -152255582, zoom: 4, layers: [], name: "Home" },
           Home: { lat: 51.9735556, lng: -152255582, zoom: 4, layers: ['basemap','cartoLayer'], name: "Home" },
           Lisgoold: { lat: 51.9735556, lng: -8.2255582, zoom: 10, layers: ['basemap','lisgooldLayer'], name: "Lisgoold" },
           Salesman: { lat: 52.484837, lng: -8.2613306, zoom: 7, layers: ['basemap','cartoLayer'], name: "Salesman" },
           England: { lat: 52.5945837, lng:-2.0337078,  zoom: 9, layers: ['basemap','cartoLayer'], name: "England" },
           SalesmanReturn: {lat: 51.9735556, lng: -8.2255582,  zoom: 10, layers: ['basemap','cartoLayer'], name: "SalesmanReturn" },
           USJourney: {lat: 52.5945837, lng:-30.0337078,  zoom: 5, layers: ['basemap','cartoLayer'], name: "USJourney" },
           WorkCanada: {lat: 48.7321991, lng:-79.7597816,  zoom: 4, layers: ['basemap','cartoLayer'], name: "WorkCanada" },
           TravelToUS: {lat: 47.0151458, lng:-94.7614612,  zoom: 6, layers: ['basemap','cartoLayer'], name: "TravelToUS" },
           WorkUS: {lat: 41.8333925, lng:-88.0121484,  zoom: 10, layers: ['basemap','cartoLayer'], name: "WorkUS" },
           Marriage: {lat: 41.8270076, lng:-87.6455073,  zoom: 14, layers: ['basemap','cartoLayer'], name: "Marriage" },
           LifeInChicago: {lat: 41.8333925, lng:-88.0121484,  zoom: 11, layers: ['basemap','cartoLayer'], name: "LifeInChicago" },
           FamilyTragedy: {lat: 41.9028448, lng:   -87.6857373,  zoom: 11, layers: ['basemap','cartoLayer'], name: "FamilyTragedy"},
           CrossingAtlantic: {lat: 52.5945837, lng:-30.0337078,  zoom: 5, layers: ['basemap','cartoLayer', 'layer4'], name: "CrossingAtlantic" },
           FamilyGraves: {lat: 41.8333925, lng:-88.0121484,  zoom: 11, layers: ['basemap','cartoLayer'], name: "FamilyGraves"},
           StillInChicago: {lat: 41.8333925, lng:-88.0121484,  zoom: 11, layers: ['basemap','cartoLayer'], name: "StillInChicago"}
};
// initializaze storymap
$('#storymap').storymap({
           scenes: scenes,
           layers: layers,
           baselayer: layers.basemap,
           legend: true,
           loader: true,
           flyto: false,
           credits: "Built with Carto, StoryMap and Leaflet, 2021",
           scalebar: true,
           scrolldown: true,
           progressline: true,
           navwidget: true,
createMap: function () {
   let map2 = L.map($(".storymap-map")[0], { zoomControl: false }).setView([30, 0], 3);
   const popup = L.popup({closeButton: true});
cartoLayer.on('featureClicked', featureEvent => {
           var popup = L.popup()
           .setLatLng(featureEvent.latLng)
           let content = '';
             if (featureEvent.data.scene) {
                content += '<p>';
                content += featureEvent.data.scene;
                content += '</p><p>';
                content += featureEvent.data.landmark_not_on_gis;
                content += '</p><p>';
                content += featureEvent.data.location_address;
              }
            var line = L.polyline([
              [51.9674951, -8.2364881],
              [52.2662119, -8.2786411],
              [52.3745288, -7.9340018],
              [52.6801578, -7.8111139],
              [52.8555496, -7.5954776],
              [52.9628186, -7.7504342],
              [52.9391769, -7.6398531],
              [52.9942281, -7.4757189],
              [53.0426599, -7.3258656],
              [53.1674088, -6.9202995],
              [53.1443264, -6.8470534],
              [53.1062715, -6.0733409],
              [53.3242381, -6.3857864],
              [53.3288689, -6.2392783],
              [53.2650105, -6.1237033],
              [53.1970187, -6.1308245],
              [52.9825088, -6.0602595],
              [52.7950711, -6.1748422],
              [52.8581642, -6.2179385],
              [52.8824992, -6.2431992],
              [52.6757346, -6.303057],
              [52.5058482, -6.5894459],
              [52.5031391, -6.5624348],
              [52.3945888, -6.9615096],
              [52.2474998, -7.1480493],
              [52.0914087, -7.6386446],
              [51.9534288, -7.8755096],
              [51.9674951, -8.2364881]
            ]);
 map2.addLayer(line);
 var animatedMarker = L.animatedMarker(line.getLatLngs());
 map2.addLayer(animatedMarker);
 // add values to Leafet popup element
 popup.setContent(content).openOn(map2);
});
 // add basemap
 this.baselayer.layer.addTo(map2);
 // add carto layer
 layers.cartoLayer.layer.addTo(map2);
 //layers.lisgooldLayer.layer.addTo(map2);
 return map2;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't escaped your quotes on the const where;

const sourceLisgoold = new carto.source.SQL('
SELECT * FROM CARTOSOURCE
WHERE scene=**'Lisgoold'**
');

Comment: Thanks for this, @Trevr - I tried that with backslashes but I get this error
(index):226 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

... and then also with a backquote character but this generates an error from StoryMap later on in the code:   
(index):428 Uncaught TypeError: layers.lisgooldLayer.addTo is not a function

Comment: Further to this, I have been editing the StoryMap section at the end to remove
layers.cartoLayer.layer.addTo(map2);
and to replace it with:
client.getLeafletLayer().addTo(map2);
in order to include the lisgooldLayer, but it gives the response:
leaflet.js:5 Uncaught Error: The provided object is not a Layer
So StoryMap doesn't seem to be adding the layer because it is not of the type layer.